# Memory leaks in simple activity

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I just check around how MAT work . For that i create a simple activity and in the UI itself I just set a layout from XML which contain a button.

Next launch the activity 3 times (back key + touching launching icon).

I got three instances of my activity in the `histogram` and `dominator tree` from google alot what I understand is that the hisogram takes the heap dump and tell you about exitence of number of object in the memory allocated via new operator.

can any one give me a reason why its not working and I am getting 3 object of my application when i launch my application 3 different time. I did nothing special in my activity not even a varible

Comment: This is java right.  And the GC has not happened then the objects will still be visible.  They will be collected at GC - no mem leak.

Comment: I'm not sure what user2310289 is saying, and why he got modded up, there should be only one activity there. Please show us some of your code.

Comment: Use DDMS to force a garbage collection and then you will see that just one activity instance will remain.

Comment: In addiction, here is a good start guide to memory management in android and also MAT: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk